# Use Connect-PnPOnline in a workflow

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-online

Good morning, everyone,
I have a problem in retrieving information from SharePoint groups. I do it in a workflow, first I get the list of all groups and then I use it in a foreach-parallel to list the members of these groups.

The problem is that the connection doesn't seem to be maintaining and my query doesn't recover all the groups.

Here is a piece of the code:

```
workflow GetGroup {
    param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [String]$SPOSite,
    [System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]$SPOCreds
    )
    $KeepAlive = Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SPOSite -Credentials $SPOCreds -ReturnConnection 
    $GetGroups = Get-PnPGroup
    ForEach -Parallel -ThrottleLimit 512 ($Group in $GetGroups)
    {
       $GroupName = $Group.LoginName
       $Users = Get-PnPGroupMembers -Identity $groupName -Connection $workFlow:KeepAlive 
    } 
 }
GetGroup -SPOSite "https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/xx -SPOCreds (Get-Credential)
```

The expected result would be an array initialized at the beginning of the workflow with a PSCustomObject object that is added to our array. This table is made up of 3 things: The name of the group, the names of the people in that group, the emails of the people.

Unfortunately the table is only partially generated because a workflow here is the error I find nothing on the subject: 
Impossible to link the "Connection" parameter. Impossible to convert the value "SharePointPnP.PowerShell.Commands.Base.SPOnlineConnection" of the type "SharePointPnP.PowerShell.Commands.
Deserialized.SharePointPnPnP.PowerShell.Commands.Base.SPOnlineConnection"

Thank you for your help.

Comment: This sounds more environmental than PowerShell specific. You should fire up Fiddler or other tools, to monitor the activity to see what is actually happening at each layer.

Comment: I think it more look like a type of value issue workflow is attending deserialized data and it getting serialized data...

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same error in a similar scenario, and this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/troubleshoot/runbooks#fails-deserialized-object) helped me. Workflow is converting the Connection object (`$KeepAlive` in your case) to a deserialized format, and so the other cmdlet doesn't accept it. You will just have to wrap those cmdlets with InlineScript, or use a PowerShell script runbook instead of a PowerShell workflow runbook.